# Why is my sbt not seeing the Android build tools?

Tags: android, sbt, sbt-android-plugin

When I do `sbt android:package-debug` in my project folder, I get this:

```
[error] (android:platform) Platform android-19 unknown in my-project-directory 
[error] (android:sdk-parser) Android SDK build-tools not found: None 
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 16, 2014 11:37:53 PM
```

I am pretty sure I've installed `android-19`. I have also set my `ANDROID_HOME` properly.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, solved it. It turns out I did not set my `ANDROID_HOME` env correctly.